# Make the current page element into a hyperlink

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, pagination

Often I will scroll the whole page of "newest" questions to the bottom and want to see the first page again because the questions update at a frequent pace. It would make sense to be able to click the `[1]` in order to be able to get the page reloaded since my mouse is already in that area. I tried clicking it and nothing happens because the 1 is a span.

[image]

Its html looks like this

```
<span class="page-numbers current">1</span>
```

And it would be very nice if it looked like this

```
<a href="/questions?page=1&amp;sort=newest" title="go to page 1"> <span class="page-numbers current">1</span> </a>
```

While this is more applicable to the first page, I think it also applies to all current pages, and is a common practice web-wide.

tldr;

Please make the current page number a link as well.

Comment: This would be just another, usually wasted step for keyboard users. Use `F5` and the `Home`/`Pos1` keys instead.

Comment: @toscho - This is not a wasted step for everyone else though, such as users who use a mouse or touch (which I would assume is at least 90%). Optimizing for keyboard only would be like supporting IE6+, and maybe some Netscape Navigator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally don't think this is worth doing.

Semantically speaking, having the "current" page be clickable makes little sense to me. And there are typically better ways to refresh pages either via keyboard shortcuts or by hitting the "refresh" button in the browser that's generally available on touch devices as well.

Comment: There are so many other places that allow the current page to be refreshed though which share the same type of semantics, such as "Questions" or "newest"/"active"/etc, or the title of a question. Are there any click statistics that SE collects for usage of those links?

Comment: @TravisJ Not that I know of. We could probably gather some, but this is a cost-vs-benefit kind of thing. (Which is to say "we probably won't wire up events to various links just to see what happens. We're content with what we got right now.) I can see people clicking more links at the top of the page (even though I personally don't), but scrolling all the way to the bottom and clicking/tapping a fairly small element just to refresh? That seems unlikely.

Comment: I agree there is no reason to gather data, I was just curious if it was already available. I guess if it seems unlikely to be used there isn't much point to it.